# Flutter switch not changing after tap even though setState is being called

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to mimic the flutter gallery app options backdrop. I have it working except the option to set the dark theme is changing the theme only once and then gets stuck there in dark mode.

the switch state always just shows false.

the source code is available here: https://github.com/manssster/nitnem

not sure if providing any code snippets will be any help as the problem seems to be obscure but here is the section that builds the widget.

```
class _ThemeItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const _ThemeItem(this.options, this.onOptionsChanged);

  final Options options;
  final ValueChanged<Options> onOptionsChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String title = 'Dark Theme';

    return _BooleanItem(
      title, options.theme == kDarkGalleryTheme, (bool value) => 
change(value), switchKey: const Key('dark_theme'),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I guess you should use StatefulWidget instead of StatelessWidget since you are going to change the State of the switch.

Comment: I actually thought about that, however the gallery example also uses stateless widget. So it seems there is something else going on here?

Comment: can you send your full code, I cant see the switch widget in the code you posted.

Comment: the full code is actually available in the github repo. I was eventually able to resolve it but still dont quite understand the root cause of the issue. I found out that when i change the routing to load the main page instead of the spash screen the behaviour work as expected. then subsequently i changed the routing code and it worked successfully. however i still dont understand the reason why it didnt work earlier.